# Get json content in wpf webbrowser window instead of download dialog box

Tags: c#, json, wpf, jwt, webbrowser-control

I have a c# application with wpf window and webbrowser on it. I want to do authentication in that wpf window using oauth. On backend i have web api 2.

**How can i get json with my responce in HtmlDocument in my webBrowser not in another file? Because when authentication is successfull, in wpf i get download dialog window with my json.**

[image: Download dialog window]

In wpf window i enter authentication values.

In wpf cs file i just send webbrowser to navigate to url with my backend controller action with all authentication processes. 
When click to download json file wpf looks:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

In webBrowser wpf:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("../api/Controller/MyAction");
```

In webApi:

```
[HttpGet]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction()
  {
     return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, MyJson.toString());
  }
```

Comment: You need to show your code. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can't you simply download the JSON as a string using the WebClient or HttpClient class instead of using a WebBrowser?